# css animation onload jQuery event

Tags: jquery, css, animation, onload

I have a `<div id="A"></div>` containing a logo and navigation menu at the top of my website. I have applied a class to the div which is causing a CSS slide down effect when items load. Naturally, the logo's image is loading slower because the menu is just rendering text buttons. I want the image to load first and then the `<div id="A"></div>` to slide down.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#A').load(function(){
    //I want the slide down effect to take place here.
  });
});
</script>
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a class, then remove the class from the HTML and add it in your jQuery.

However, since you're using jQuery to see if the image has loaded, you might as well use a jQuery `.animate` function, since it'll work in more browsers that way.

Comment: Well, I've tried your solution, yet it's not working. Here's my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/blueclue/93Pgh/6/